# need a warning about overriding a function with const parameter

Tags: android, c++, g++, constants, porting

*How do I make GCC inform me about redefining member functions with a different signature?*

I am porting a large project to Android.
Due to the differences in the M$VC and GCC dialects, I inserted a number of `const` modifiers for function parameters.
(Namely, when you call `func(MyClass(something))`, M$ is ok with `MyClass&` while GCC requires `const MyClass&`.)

The gotcha is that when you change the signature of `BaseClass::func()`, you get no warning about having a different signature for `DerivedClass::func()`.

Here is a small program showing what's going on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    class Value {
       int x;
       public:
       Value(int xx):x(xx){}
  };
    class Base {
       public:
       virtual void f(const Value&v) {printf("Base\n");}
  };
    class First: public Base {
       public:
       virtual void f(Value&v) {printf("First\n");}
  };
    class Second: public Base {
       public:
       virtual void f(Value&v) {printf("Second\n");}
  };

    int main() {
         Value v(1);
         First first;
         Second second;
         Base*any;
         any = &first;
         any->f(v);
         any->f(Value(2));
         first.f(v);
    //first.f(Value(3)); // error: no matching function for call to 
         First::f(Value)
}
```

When I compile and run it, I get:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra inher2.cpp 
    inher2.cpp:10:18: warning: unused parameter ‘v’
    inher2.cpp:15:18: warning: unused parameter ‘v’
    inher2.cpp:20:18: warning: unused parameter ‘v’
$ ./a.out 
    Base
    Base
    First
$
```

(gcc is right about the unused parameter, but it's irrelevant.)

So:
**How do I make GCC inform me about redefining member functions with a different signature?**

Answer (score 4):

That should be -Woverloaded-virtual.

> -Woverloaded-virtual
>
> ```
>  Warn when a derived class function declaration may be an error in
>  defining a virtual function (C++ only).  In a derived class, the
>  definitions of virtual functions must match the type signature of a
>  virtual function declared in the base class.  With this option, the
>  compiler warns when you define a function with the same name as a
>  virtual function, but with a type signature that does not match any
>  declarations from the base class.
> ```

Comment: This is _much_ better than nothing, but it's not a perfect solution either. I get _lots_ of messages like ``void func(SomeType&) is hidden by SomeType func()`` when I am really interested only in those that differ in ``const`` modifiers.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 Then I can't help. Those are all things to be concerned about. Why would you even get that many hidden functions - crappy naming convention?

Comment: _Because_ the code is written _decades_ ago, and not by me. Some files date back to 1994.